# On the function $n \mapsto |a_n|^{\frac 1n}$ for a given power series $\sum_{n} a_n z^n$

Tags: reference-request, power-series, analytic-functions

I am currently doing research involving power series on the unit disk in $\Bbb C$: precisely I am studying the properties of converging power series of a standard form
$$
f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where (assuming conventionally for the discourse that $0\notin\Bbb N$)

1. $\limsup_{\substack{n\in\Bbb N \\n\to\infty}} |a_n|^{\frac 1n}=1$, and
2. $z\in \Bbb D=\{z\in\Bbb C : |z|<1\}$.

From the basic properties of $\limsup$, condition 1 implies the boundedness of the set $\big\{|a_n|^{\frac 1n}\big\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ , i.e. it implies the existence of $\sup_{\substack{n\in\Bbb N \\n\to\infty}} |a_n|^{\frac 1n}$, and this has some important consequences on the structure of \eqref{1}, namely an estimate of the size of zero free regions, the size of the minimal univalence radius etc., described in an old paper by Milos Kössler [1].

**The question**

*The paper* [1] *focuses on what a finite value of $\sup_{\substack{n\in\Bbb N \\n\to\infty}} |a_n|^{\frac 1n}$ implies: does there exist other studies trying to analyze the implications of a given behavior for $n \mapsto |a_n|^{\frac 1n}$, $n\in \Bbb N$ or for the related $n \mapsto \sup_{k>n}|a_k|^{\frac 1k}$*?

**References**

[1] Milos Kössler, "[O významu čísla $\sup |a_n|^{\frac 1n}$ v teorii mocninných řad (The signification of the number $\sup |a_n|^{\frac 1n}$ in the theory of power series)](https://dml.cz/manakin/handle/10338.dmlcz/109149)", (Czech, English summary), Časopis Pro Pěstování Matematiky a Fysiky 74, No. 1, 47-53 (1949), [MR0034833](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0034833), [Zbl 0033.26504](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:Zbl%200033.26504&format=complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: I've modified my latest note by including materials on references I got aware thanks to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424485/113756)

---

At the beginning of its mathematical career, [Shmuel Agmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_Agmon) wrote several complex analysis papers dealing with the singularities of Taylor series, possibly under the influence of its advisor [Szolem Mandelbrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szolem_Mandelbrojt). In one of them (see [1], chapter 1, §§ 1.1 and 1.2 pp. 264-265, but for a clearer exposition [2], §3 p. 497), he considers a class of real valued function $\omega:\Bbb R_{\ge 0}\to\Bbb R$ such that
$$
\limsup_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\omega(x)}{x}=0
$$
(and note that $\limsup_{n\to+\infty} \ln|a_n|/n=0\iff \limsup_{n\to+\infty} |a_n|^{1\over n}=1$)
he proves that, for each function $\omega$ in this class there exists a function $C(x)$ such that

1. $C(x)$ is a majorant for $\omega(x)$ in the sense that $C(x)\ge\omega(x)$,
2. $C(x)$ is concave, i.e. $C(x+h)+C(x-h)-2C(x)\le 0$ for $h>0$ and $x-h\ge 0$,
3. $C(x)$ is the unique smallest real function having the two preceding properties.

He calls the function $C(x)$ the *smallest concave majorant* or *envelope* of $\omega$. 
Now it is clear that, by considering the real function $|a_n|:\Bbb N\to \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, the above results imply that there exists its smallest concave envelope $C(n) =c_n$, and it is such that
$$
c_n \ge \ln|a_n|\iff e^{c_n} \ge |a_n| \ge 0. \label{2}\tag{2}
$$
Equation \eqref{2} allows already for an estimation of  the coefficients of \eqref{1}: however, a more important property of $C(x)$ ([2], §3 p. 497) is known, i.e. that
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{C(x)}{x}=0 \iff \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{c_n}{n}=0
$$
and this implies that $e^{c_n} = O(k^n)$ for some $k>0$ and $n>N$ as $n\to \infty$. And if, for example, \eqref{1} converges for $z=1$, then \eqref{2} can be used to deduce precise power like decreasing estimates for the its sequence of coefficients $\{ a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

**Notes**

- I found references [1] and [2] nearly two months ago, while searching for references related to the classical Fatou-Riesz theorem. It was some kind of surprise for me since I acknowledged Agmon as a specialist in PDEs and not in complex analysis: however, it was a good surprise.
- In [1], chapter 1, §1.2 p. 265 Agmon states that the function $C(x)$ was introduced by Georges Valiron for the study of entire functions: thanks to [this answer by Alexandre Eremenko](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424485/113756), I had a look at the original references (see the cited answer for bibliographic indications). The construction of $C(x)$ is a generalization to power series of the construction of [Newton's polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) for a polynomial: Valiron goes by calling it "Hadamard polygon" as Hadamard seems the first to have used this construction in his famous 1893 paper on the Riemann function ([3], §2-5, pp. 172-175).

**References**

[1] Shmuel Agmon, "[Sur les séries de Dirichlet](https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.971)" (French), Annales Scientifiques de l’École Normale Supérieure, Troisième (III) Série 66, 263-310 (1949), [MR0033352](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0033352), [Zbl 0034.34602](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0034.34602).

[2] Shmuel Agmon, "[Functions of exponential type in an angle and singularities of Taylor series](https://doi.org/10.2307/1990611)" (English), Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 70, 492-508 (1951), [MR0041222](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0041222), [Zbl 0045.34902](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0045.34902).

[3] Jacques Hadamard, "[Étude sur les propriétés des fonctions entières et en particulier d’une fonction considérée par Riemann](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k97014644/f179.item)"(French), Journal de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées, Quatrième (4) Série, vol. IX, 171-215 (1893), [JFM 25.0698.03](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A25.0698.03).